# Term for continous/progressive aspect in German

Tags: grammar, terminology

The article "Verlaufsform" on the German Wikipedia links to "continuous and progressive aspects" in English.

According to English WP, "continuous" denote a current state, like "She is wearing a red gown", while "progressive" denotes a current event or action, like "It is raining". English does not distinguish between these two, but apparently some other languages do.

There exists the term "Progressiver Aspect" and "Progressiv", which is used for the German am-Progressiv, but how would "continuous aspect" be translated? Kontinuierlicher Aspekt?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be translated to *kontinuierlicher Aspekt.*

> Diskontinuierlicher und **kontinuierlicher Aspekt** der Wahrnehmung
>   <sup>[Peter Fröhlicher: Theorie und Praxis der Analyse französischer Texte: eine Einführung](http://books.google.de/books?id=u6VXh1_BuHQC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=kontinuierlicher%20aspekt&source=bl&ots=c5qWQ-vadQ&sig=NWdAd52hneEi54TFL8N76Ut7wIY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=AFVgVLDIBNG4ogSm9YHICQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwCQ)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you back your answer up in any way? An Internet search does not yield many results for this term, let alone grammar-related ones.

Comment: It is used in Books if this helps you :) http://books.google.de/books?id=u6VXh1_BuHQC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=kontinuierlicher+aspekt&source=bl&ots=c5qWQ-vadQ&sig=NWdAd52hneEi54TFL8N76Ut7wIY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=AFVgVLDIBNG4ogSm9YHICQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwCQ

Comment: @GlabbichRulz: Wrzlmprmft commented not for their own but to give you an idea what we expect to see in a good post, and to help you improve it. Other people visiting the site should find any statements made being backed up by examples, links, or whatsoever... a single liner - though possible - usually will not meet this qualtiy standard we all try to follow. For now I edited your comment as a quote to your answer to show you how this can easily be done. Feel free to add further or better (!) references if you had any. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is "kontinuierlicher Aspekt", according to [Das Verbalsystem der königlichen und privaten Inschriften: XVIII. Dynastie bis einschliesslich Amenophis III.](http://books.google.de/books?id=QkF4QhSGWtwC) (Page 66). It gives a good overview over the aspect system with other sources.